# How can i speed up this code? Apply and for loop is really slowing it down

Tags: python, pandas

I have this function that aims to calculate missingness for a list of variables (approximately 40) then summarize/"group" the results to column values, 'county'. The code is as follows:

```
def missing_count(df, var=None):
    percent_missing= df[var].eq(-999).sum() * 100 / len(df)
    return round(percent_missing,2)

for var in varlist1:
    df2[var] = df.loc[df[var]!=-888].groupby('countyName').apply(missing_count, var=var)
```

How can I speed up this code? I'm aware that for-loops/apply is quite slow. I'm trying to vectorize the code but can't get it to work.

Comment: It would help if you could paste your dataframe and the expected output.

Comment: i can't paste my dataframe because of data sharing agreements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Edited answer**

With your actual data, please replace `vars` by your target-columns, `2` by `-999` (it'll be defined as missing), and "smoker" by "countyName". Hopefully it should work.

#### Example data

```
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
df = sns.load_dataset('tips')
vars = ['total_bill', 'tip'] # target-columns
```

#### Using [`datatable`](https://datatable.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)

```
import datatable as dt
df_t = dt.Frame(df)
df2 = df_t[:, {k: dt.sum(dt.f[k]==2)/dt.count()*100 for k in vars}, dt.by('smoker')]
```

Output:

```
   | smoker  total_bill      tip
-- + ------  ----------  -------
 0 | No               0  11.9205
 1 | Yes              0  16.129
```

#### Using [`pandas`](https://pandas.pydata.org/) + [`numpy`](https://numpy.org/)

```
df2 = df.groupby('smoker')[vars].agg(lambda x: (x==2).sum() / x.size * 100)
```

Output:

```
        total_bill        tip
smoker                       
Yes            0.0  16.129032
No             0.0  11.920530
```

Comment: In which step? Maybe would be best to provide a small example for us. Make sure `(df[vars].values==-999)` is returning a boolean numpy 2D-array.

Comment: the last step where df2 is created. the resulting "rec" series gives 67 values (this is how many counties there are - however, it created only one column) containing 67 values like: 

[1.00000000e+02 1.00000000e+02 1.00000000e+02 0.00000000e+00
 1.00000000e+02 0.00000000e+00 1.00000000e+02 0.00000000e+00
 0.00000000e+00 1.13170732e+01 1.00000000e+02 9.84390244e+01
 0.00000000e+00 0.00000000e+00 0.00000000e+00 1.00000000e+02
 0.00000000e+00 2.85853659e+01 6.82926829e-01 3.56097561e+00
 2.71707317e+01 2.43902439e-01 9.66829268e+01 9.94146341e+01]

Comment: if instead of trying to run on a list of columns, if i run on only one column contained in a list, e.g.: vars = ['offense'] the keyerror is the same.

Comment: running by itself: (df.Offense.values==-999).sum()/(len(df.index)) gives me an exponential values too

Comment: I edited the answer to include a reproducible example. See if you can get it to work. If so, probably it's something with your data. Which is the data type from your columns (e.g. "Offense") ?

Comment: results from describe:

<bound method NDFrame.describe of 0        -888.0
1         290.0
2         185.0
3         185.0
4         185.0
 
517419    350.0
517420    465.0
517421    465.0
517422    465.0
517423    465.0
Name: Offense, Length: 517424, dtype: float32>

Comment: If you can't get his code to work (while I can), I assume it might be some version-related issue. My pandas version is 1.1.3, and numpy 1.19.2. Sorry not be able to help. It worked well in my machine.

Comment: "None of [Index([                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                (1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, etc are in [columns]

Comment: alright, thanks anyway, i appreciate it. if you think of anything else feel free to PM me.

Comment: this worked! so much faster. thank you!!!! the pandas+numpy option sealed the deal